# attributeGroup in xsd and its representation in xml

Tags: xml, eclipse, spring, xsd, spring-security

Given this XSD from [this document](http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd)

```
<xs:element name="jdbc-user-service" substitutionGroup="security:any-user-service">
    <xs:annotation> .. etc </xs:annotation>
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:token"></xs:attribute>
        <xs:attributeGroup ref="security:jdbc-user-service.attlist"/>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

<xs:attributeGroup name="jdbc-user-service.attlist">
    <xs:attribute name="data-source-ref" use="required" type="xs:token">
    </xs:attribute>
    <xs:attribute name="cache-ref" type="xs:token">
    </xs:attribute>
    <xs:attribute name="users-by-username-query" type="xs:token">
    </xs:attribute>
    <xs:attribute name="authorities-by-username-query" type="xs:token">
    </xs:attribute>
    <xs:attribute name="group-authorities-by-username-query" type="xs:token">     
    </xs:attribute>
    <xs:attribute name="role-prefix" type="xs:token">
    </xs:attribute>
</xs:attributeGroup>
```

then why is eclipse giving me this error

> cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'jdbc-user-service'. One of '{"http://
>    www.springframework.org/schema/security":user}' is expected.

when I provide the following XML?

```
<jdbc-user-service
    data-source-ref="dataSource"
    users-by-username-query="SELECT u.uname, u.upwd, u.enabled FROM ucsdb.users u WHERE u.uname = ?"/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you're mixing things up. You're probably getting this error from **another** XML. The XML you've posted (assuming namespaces are correct, see below just in case) is **valid** according to the XSD.

```
<jdbc-user-service xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security" data-source-ref="dataSource" users-by-username-query="SELECT u.uname, u.upwd, u.enabled FROM ucsdb.users u WHERE u.uname = ?"/>
```

The only "user" element in the posted XSD comes from this element:

```
<xs:element name="user-service" substitutionGroup="security:any-user-service">
    <xs:annotation>
        <xs:documentation>Creates an in-memory UserDetailsService from a properties file or a list of "user" child elements. Usernames are converted to lower-case internally to allow for case-insensitive lookups, so this should not be used if case-sensitivity is required.</xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="user">
                <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:documentation>Represents a user in the application.</xs:documentation>
                </xs:annotation>
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:attributeGroup ref="security:user.attlist"/>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:token">
            <xs:annotation>
                <xs:documentation>A bean identifier, used for referring to the bean elsewhere in the context.</xs:documentation>
            </xs:annotation>
        </xs:attribute>
        <xs:attributeGroup ref="security:properties-file"/>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

So you **must** be validating an XML that uses the "user-service" tag instead.